# Rails singular resource does't seem to generate 'user_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following routes in my 3.1.0.rc5 app

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users
resources :users, only: :index
resource :user
```

THe idea here is that I use devise for session management, the 'users' resource just to generate the `users_path` for the index action and then most other user actions would be accessible via routes like

- `GET user_path` -> show action
- `GET new_user_path` -> new action
- `POST user_path` -> create action

The `user_path` route helper doesn't seem to be generated though, whenever I try to use it in a view, I get a weird error when rails tries to render it.

For example, on the `/user/new` page, I have the following

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => user_path do |f| %>
  # omitted form elements
<% end %>
```

When rails tries to render the page I get

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}):
    7: </div>
    8: 
    9: <div class="content_middle">
    10:   <%= form_for @user, :url => user_path do |f| %>
    11:   <fieldset>
    12:     <%= render partial: "form_errors" %>
    13: 
  app/views/users/new.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___1548382046039026466_2191201580'
```

What's up with that!?

**Edit** Here is the content of rake routes. It's pretty massive so I cut it down to just the user related routes.

```
       new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
   destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                    {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
          user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                    {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
     edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)               {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                        PUT    /users/password(.:format)                    {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                        POST   /users(.:format)                             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
                   user DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
                        POST   /user(.:format)                              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
               new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
              edit_user GET    /user/edit(.:format)                         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                        GET    /user(.:format)                              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                        PUT    /user(.:format)                              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
```

Comment: Paste the output of **rake routes**

Comment: I added the user related parts of rake routes

Comment: I thought the point of resource was that there is no user_path. You shouldn't need a path to any user in particular since you are only accessing one, hence the name 'resource'.

Comment: @Max That's why it's `user_path` instead of `users_path`.  It just doesn't take an id.

Comment: What version of devise are you running?  I just threw together a sample app with the same Rails version and it works fine.  Also, couldn't you just name the single user paths "current_user" or "profile" or something and save all the confusion?

Comment: @numbers, I'm using 1.4.2 which is latest afaik. I'll try setting up a ProfilesController and see how that goes.

Comment: @numbers. I did what you suggested and made a profiles controller. I like it and it works so if you want to throw that comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make sense to have a `Profile` or `CurrentUser` controller in this situation.  It would eliminate any routing conflicts you may be having with Devise, and also, it makes sense from a RESTful point of view as you're treating the current user as a distinct resource.

```
devise_for :user
resources :users, :only => :index
resource :profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with devise. What helped me was to add `as: :user` to the singular route.

```
get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', as: :user
```

Then I could cal it as `user_path` or pass the argument `user_path(current_user)`